# Origin of Reciting Psalms

Tags: minhag, tefilla, sources-mekorot, tehilim-psalms, provenance

What is the origin of reciting Tehillim as a form of prayer? More specifically, of reciting even passages of Tehillim which do not contain requests for the issue one is facing but rather of praise of God and the like.
Earliest sources would be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://mi.yodeya.com/q/44058? And similar to http://mi.yodeya.com/q/5527.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4622/759

Comment: @msh210 Doesn't appear to be a duplicate. None of those ask what the source is of connecting tehillim in particular with prayer. Rather they asked about details such as finishing the whole book.

Answer (score 1):

The practice seems to have at least predated Rambam (12th century) who seems to reference it in Hilkhot Avodah Zarah ([ch. 11](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1411.htm)):

> הלוחש על המכה וקורא פסוק מן התורה, וכן הקורא על התינוק שלא ייבעת, המניח ספר תורה או תפילין על הקטן בשביל שיישן--לא דיי להן שהן בכלל חוברים ומנחשים:  אלא שהן בכלל הכופרים בתורה, שהן עושין דברי תורה רפאות גוף, ואינן אלא רפאות נפשות, שנאמר "ויהיו חיים, לנפשך" (משלי ג,כב).  אבל הבריא שקרא פסוקין **או מזמור מתילים**, כדי שתגן עליו זכות קריאתן, ויינצל מצרות ונזקים--הרי זה מותר

Of all of the books in the Bible, he singles out Psalms as a source for verses to be recited to effect a desired outcome.